# How to get buffered/cached memory size in C++ under Linux?

Tags: c++, linux

I want to warn the user when memory available is low. Currently I'm using `sysconf(_SC_PHYS_PAGES)` to get the number of physical pages available.

However, there is also memory that the OS uses as buffer and cache. How do I obtain them programmatically?

Comment: Consider reading `/proc/meminfo` instead of using `sysconf()`; it provides quite an exhaustive report on memory usage.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way the free command from procps does it is by reading the `/proc/meminfo` file. You can see their source [here](http://procps.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/procps/procps/proc/sysinfo.c?revision=1.41&view=markup). The meminfo function updates globals, in particular kb_main_buffers and kb_main_cached. You could probably reuse their code to do what you want. (Assuming your license is compatible)