# What's the most efficient way to get the "available memory" in Linux by c++?

Tags: c++, linux

As shown in "/proc/meminfo" - MemAvailable: 12345 kB
What's the best way of getting this value? Parsing the file is slow; using sysinfo.h is fast but it doesn't have such field.
Or if MemAvail = free + cached + buffered, where to get the "cached" size?

Thank you!

Comment: you can use cmd 'free'

Comment: thanks! but still this is not as fast as in memory accessing like struct sysinfo. So any more advice?

Comment: Have you tried the `sysconf` solution in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2513561/1553090)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12699557/how-to-get-buffered-cached-memory-size-in-c-under-linux

Comment: Thanks I did simple try with reading some source code, but fail before. well maybe I need more patience:) I'll try it again.